# Synchronising Ubuntu 20.04 across multiple machines

Tags: sync, rsync, unison

I'm aware that this is not the first time this is asked but I have not been able to find an answer that was younger than 5 years and still up to date.

Currently, I have Ubuntu 20.04 on my Desktop at home and I'm very happy with how it's set up. I'm going to buy and set up a laptop to be able to work while travelling and I want the setup to be the exact same.

This means:

- Synchronizing software
- Synchronizing the softwares configuration (especially VSCode)
- Synchronizing selected folders

I have stumbled upon solutions like

- syncthing
- rsync
- unison

but I have not been able to figure out if they are fully capable (especially the software configuration part) or what the exact difference between those three is. If someone could save me the headache of working and testing through those options, I would appreciate it.

Comment: I think this question might be "too broad" for this site, or potentially off-topic since there is a [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) site.

Comment: Syncing software config files, like all the dotfiles in your home directly is a fine idea. So is syncing selected files. All stuff hopefully in your `$HOME` directory. But I don't think syncing large software/programs from computer to computer is a good idea. Why not use the package manager on each machine to ensure your installed software is up-to-date with the repos?

Comment: Hey Mike,
thank you for giving this question a shot. I realise that the "one software that handles it all" solution most likely doesn't exist. I think I have somewhat of a handle on most issues now except for the packages. My issue is that package dependencies are sometimes a bit tricky and I want to avoid having to download packages on the road because I I forgot to download one at home. How could I synchronize packages across two machines? (I do my work mainly on a desktop but want to be able to work in a similar environment on my laptop when I'm on the road)

Comment: Doing a cursory search, I don't see a quick way to sync packages automatically. You can do something [like this](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/agixs/is_there_something_that_can_synchronize_installed/) to get your two computers in sync initially, but then just remember to install any new package on both machines after this. I explicitly keep a list of packages I use for when I have to set up a new computer.

Comment: Ok, I guess that'll do. I'll mark it as completed. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give you a quick rundown:

- Syncthing I'm not sure about.
- rsync is like a beefed up scp. You'll need to write a script or cron job using rsync if you want the synchronization to be automatic.
- unison is great if you have the same OS and OS version on the machines you're syncing. It's critical that the same version of unison be used on each machine. This is like an even more beefed up version of scp, so you'll need one of your machines running unison as a daemon and able to access the other one via ssh. It works better if you have a third *central* server, like a backup server, that each computer stays in sync with.

Searching around for "*keeping linux computers in sync*" there are a ton of other tools for this too.